# Object List in kendo-grid mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo-grid with a certain number of fields which derive from my model, recently I added a `List<Entity>` to this model. However when I try to load my grid while the list is not null it just fails to load anything at all. I know that this happens because a nested object isn't supported by the kendo-grid by default. I haven't added anything for this List in my view yet and I'm wondering how to accomplish this.

There's one error message I get while loading the data which is:

System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.BinLocation_Item_5FB823DBD32445977E0B51123416DFB49CA7B0CAA42A233C8DB7B8E94493BEEE'.

Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LineNum { get; set; }

    public string ArticleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ArticleID { get; set; }

    public List<Location_Item> locations { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Put 'db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;' before database call to fill your model

Comment: Its telling me my list is null now (the list in the model returned to the view is not). I guess this is because of kendo-grid itself. I also added a default value to the field in my view where I created a new list with values however these are null aswell (without errors though).

Comment: Right the list came through however it ain't possible to use this inside of the grid. I'll be using the data somewhere outside of it then. The proxycreation did however solve my problem of the data not loading cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Like Curiousdev said set "db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;" did the trick for loading the data. Getting the list data in the grid didn't quite work however and will be displayed in some other way.